# Beamer - unable to move image + caption downwards

Tags: beamer, floats, captions, positioning

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usetheme[titleformat=allcaps, progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Apoptosis facilitates antigen presentation to T lymphocytes through MHC-I and CD1 in tuberculosis}
\subtitle{ \small Schaible \emph{et al.} (2003)}
\date{February 18, 2016}
\author{Demo}
\institute{Demo}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo/logo}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle





\begin{frame}{\emph{M. tuberculosis} antigens and particulates are confined within the phagosome}
   \begin{columns}
    \column{0.7\textwidth}%
    \vspace*{-1cm}\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{mycobacteriumvstubcerolosis.png}
  \vspace*{1cm}\captionof{figure}{\footnotesize Left quadrant: dyes from labeled- \emph{M. tuberculosis} remain confined within phagosomes. Right quadrant: dyes from labeled-\emph{L. monocytogenes} were released into the cell <10 mins after infection. Arrows indicate bacteria-containing phagosomes.}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \itemsep1em
    \item The mycobacterial phagosome appears to be impermeable to macromolecules
    \item Membrane-impermeable fluorescent molecules were \alert{retained} in phagosomes across all maturation stages
    \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\pause
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{alertblock}{Seclusion from the classical MHC-I pathway is apparent.}
      There must be another alternative pathway for antigen delivery.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to move the image here downwards, but it won't move. Even with vspace, the image moves down, but the caption moves upwards. It's covering the progress bar and doesn't quite look that good.

Thanks for the help guys.

[image]

Comment: Basically it is because there is not enough space on the frame. What your example picture doesn't show is the alertblock you add under the picture and the itemize environment. Apart from that: Is there a reason why you do not use the figure environment for your picture? And a last remark: If you are having trouble fitting something onto a frame imho you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Benjamin To invert the question: Is there a reason one should use figure environment for an image in beamer? Beamer does not use floats and redefines the figure environment to little more than centring the image.

Comment: Yes I think so. Firstly I often copy&paste images from papers into the presentation and there the figure environment is already there. So why remove it? Secondly I don't have to use `captionof` for the caption. Thirdly the distances (before, after the image and between caption and image) are reasonably set. colonelk1 uses `\vspace*{}` here to achieve that, which I think is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust your frame, you have to play with the `vspace`. I think you should use the `em` unity for them. For instance `\vspace{1em}` add a vertical space of 1 character.

To make beamer not overlapping your progression bar, you have to tell him that the frame is not higher than its limits. Thus I mainly add negative space `\vspace{-1em}` at the bottom of your frame and after your figure to obtain your expected result.

```
\begin{frame}{\emph{M. tuberculosis} antigens and particulates are confined within the phagosome}
   \begin{columns}
   \column{0.7\textwidth}%
   \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{mycobacteriumvstubcerolosis.png}
   \vspace*{-.5em}\captionof{figure}{\footnotesize Left quadrant: dyes from labeled- \emph{M. tuberculosis} remain confined within phagosomes. Right quadrant: dyes from labeled-\emph{L. monocytogenes} were released into the cell <10 mins after infection. Arrows indicate bacteria-containing phagosomes.}
   \column{0.4\textwidth}
   \begin{itemize}
      \itemsep1em
      \item The mycobacterial phagosome appears to be impermeable to macromolecules
      \item Membrane-impermeable fluorescent molecules were \alert{retained} in phagosomes across all maturation stages
   \end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\vspace{-1em}
\pause
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{alertblock}{Seclusion from the classical MHC-I pathway is apparent.}
      There must be another alternative pathway for antigen delivery.
\end{alertblock}
\vspace{-1em}
\end{frame}
```

When I compile this example, it works as you wish.